# Symfony One-To-One Unidirectional relationship How can I make Doctrine create a new Menu if a new Coffeeshop is made?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.1

I have a bit of a problem figuring out the following:
How can I make Symfony insert a new menu when a new coffeeshop has been made with a form? (foreign key in menu is shopid)

Thanks in advance, code below.

Menu Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;


/**
 * Menu
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MenuRepository")
 *
 */
class Menu
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Coffeeshop")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="coffeeshop_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $shopId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */

    private $updated;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set shopId
     *
     * @param integer $shopId
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function setShopId($shopId)
    {
        $this->shopId = $shopId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shopId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getShopId()
    {
        return $this->shopId;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastUpdated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $lastUpdated
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function setLastUpdated($lastUpdated)
    {
        $this->lastUpdated = $lastUpdated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastUpdated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getLastUpdated()
    {
        return $this->lastUpdated;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }
}
```

Coffeeshop Entity:

```
    <?php
/// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="coffeeshop")
 */
class Coffeeshop
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $streetName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=6)
     */
    private $houseNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=7)
     */
    private $zipcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */

    private $description;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set streetName
     *
     * @param string $streetName
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setStreetName($streetName)
    {
        $this->streetName = $streetName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get streetName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStreetName()
    {
        return $this->streetName;
    }

    /**
     * Set houseNumber
     *
     * @param string $houseNumber
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setHouseNumber($houseNumber)
    {
        $this->houseNumber = $houseNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get houseNumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHouseNumber()
    {
        return $this->houseNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set zipcode
     *
     * @param string $zipcode
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setZipcode($zipcode)
    {
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zipcode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getZipcode()
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set menu
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Menu $menu
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setMenu(\AppBundle\Entity\Menu $menu = null)
    {
        $this->menu = $menu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get menu
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Menu
     */
    public function getMenu()
    {
        return $this->menu;
    }

    /**
     * Set coffeeshopmenu
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Menu $coffeeshopmenu
     *
     * @return Coffeeshop
     */
    public function setCoffeeshopmenu(\AppBundle\Entity\Menu $coffeeshopmenu = null)
    {
        $this->coffeeshopmenu = $coffeeshopmenu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get coffeeshopmenu
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Menu
     */
    public function getCoffeeshopmenu()
    {
        return $this->coffeeshopmenu;
    }
}
```

Coffeeshop FormBuilder:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: 
 * Date: 23-9-2016
 * Time: 14:20
 */

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;


class CoffeeshopType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('streetName')
            ->add('houseNumber')
            ->add('zipcode')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Add shop'))
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In many ways:

- you can define `Coffeeshoptype`as a service, then inject `ManagerRegistry` (`@doctrine`) to `__construct()` (or just `EntityManager`), set an event listener for event `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT`. Something like that:

  `$this->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {/*...*/});`
- in controller, where you persist changes from `Coffeeshoptype`
- use an event listener for Doctrine (or create an entity listener, feature from Doctrine). With doctrine events, you can find if entity (`Coffeeshop`) is persisting or updating and depends of situation, create new menu.

All of above methods can have access to Doctrine (thanks to Dependency Injection), also some of these methods are bad approaches. I suggest to attach EventListener (or EventSubscriber) to one of Doctrine Events and then do persisting for new menu. But if you need to create a new menu only when Coffeeshop is submitted by form, create event listener in form type.